# How to highlight a navigation menu partial according to what url the user is on?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, url, navigation

I have a partial called `_navigation.html.erb` in my `views/shared/` folder:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

What's the "Rails" way to make this navigation menu highlight the appropriate link? Does Rails have a way to determine the current URL and **should I even use that**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you define `before_filter` in your controllers, this filter will set a certain variable depending on `action_name`, then you could use that value to render `active` for the links you want to activate. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037552/current-controller-path-without-specifying-a-action-in-rails).

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<ul>
  <li class=<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "home" %>>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

if you have the same controller for multiple menus then you can add "action" in condition

```
<ul>
  <li class=<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "home" && params[:action] == "index" %>>Home</li>
  <li class=<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "home" && params[:action] == "about" %>>About</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this gem Active Link To. It highligts those automatically
https://github.com/twg/active_link_to